# Create a general config section within activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to create a general settings section where admin users can manage/edit things like website meta tag, social media links etc. I am using activeadmin but cant work out how to achieve this..... any ideas or resources online I can read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a model for this (like `WebsiteInformation`) and add it as an activeadmin resource, then just query for those values of `WebsiteInformation` when you build your markup.